# I want to push a ball in the direction of a target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

`Shoot();` should add some force to the ball and push in direction of an object "pointTarget", but when `Shoot();` work it adds force in -x direction. How I can fix this, if you show I will be so grateful Sorry for my English

```
private void Shoot()
{
    var heading = pointTarget.position - transform.position;
    var distance = heading.normalized;
    go_ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(distance * ShootForce, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
```

Comment: To which object is this script attached?

Comment: you don't seem to ever use the "heading" variable

Answer (score 0):

`heading.normalized` does not give you distance, it gives you direction vector. You have to use `magnitude` to get the distance. Since the distance is `float`, the multiplication problem is also solved:

```cs
var distance = heading.magnitude;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your direction is incorrect, it should start with the rigidbody itself.

```
var heading = pointTarget.position - go_ball.transform.position;
```